# How to write the rephrased questions of others research paper?

Tags: quoting

I am currently writing a research paper in which I need to rephrase the other researcher text. One simple way is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
As farah has written 

\begin{center}
" This question could be interesting to do ...."
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to write or some command or tool which can be helpful? I also want to cite him/her properly while referring to him/her. I want the text to be in the center.

Comment: @marmot To center it, is it not sufficient to add `\centering`: `\begin{quote}\centering
  This question could be interesting to do ....  
\end{quote}`?

Comment: For citing, see here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management. If you have another problem, please feel free to ask any question you like.

Comment: I’d use `quote`, no centering, because this is not a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marmot said in his comment, you could use `quote` environment, to center it just use `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
As farah has written 
\begin{quote}\centering
  This question could be interesting to do \dots  
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Since you have to do it many times, you could use:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\centering}
```

to center every `quote` environment without having to write `\centering` every time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\centering}

\begin{document}
As farah has written 
\begin{quote}
  This question could be interesting to do \dots  
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, as the commenters say, you probably need only `quote` without `\centering`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
As farah has written \begin{quote}
  This question could be interesting to do \dots. But as all the commenters say, it is much better without \verb|\centering|!
\end{quote}
Something just to show you the way \verb|quote| environment works.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If real cite references to a bib are wanted too, I  suggest to check the csquotes package.

Comment: this only looks OK as it's one line, I suspect that if you had multi-line quotation you'd want to center the indented block but justify the actual text as unjustified centered text looks rather odd. That is you'd want quote without the `\centering`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The OP is using `center` isn't the result the same?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Using `center` would also look wrong for a multi-line quote. Each line would be centered separately.